# Insert Dataframe data into a map using Geopandas

Tags: python, coordinates, geopandas, pandas, plot

I posted my question in stackoverflow previously, howeverI think this site is a better place to find some clues (this is my first project with spacial data).

I need to insert some coordinates from a dataframe to a NYC map. For this task I am using geopandas. This is my code:

```
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(DF, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(DF.pickup_longitude, DF.pickup_latitude))
```

I got the following:

```
 Unnamed: 0  DOLocationID  ...  time                    geometry
0           0           NaN  ...     0.380278  POINT (-74.01576 40.71555)
1           1           NaN  ...     0.390833  POINT (-73.98205 40.76276)
2           2           NaN  ...     0.350556  POINT (-73.97941 40.75543)
3           3           NaN  ...     0.503056  POINT (-73.77679 40.64509)
4           4           NaN  ...     0.618333  POINT (-73.78806 40.64167)

[5 rows x 31 columns]
```

Then I create the map using this code:

First

```
gdf.crs = 4326
gdf = gdf.to_crs(3857)
```

Then:

```
df = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('nybb'))
df = df.to_crs(epsg=3857)
ax = df.plot(figsize=(10, 10), alpha=0.5, edgecolor='k')
ctx.add_basemap(ax)
```

[image]

As you see, NYC becomes into the entire continent.

My question is: how do I plot the geometry column into the map accurately?

Answer (score 1):

I do not have your data and have not tried to replicate this but in past experience with Geopandas and reprojecting I have found it is important to watch out using integers. Integers values in place of projection ESPG values can often cause errors and if they do not you may think things are fine. See these lines here:

```
gdf.crs = 4326
gdf = gdf.to_crs(3857)
df = df.to_crs(epsg=3857)
```

and my suggestion would be to make sure you try it like this (as the Geopandas docs say)

```
gdf.crs = "EPSG:4326"
gdf = gdf.to_crs("EPSG:3857")
df = df.to_crs("EPSG:3857")
```

If this does not solve it then my other suggestion would be to keep the data in the original projection (data is king) and the basemap should be the one to be warping. Especially with an area that is small like NYC then you should not see massive differences in your end result. Hope this helps

Comment: This will likely solve the problem. See https://geopandas.org/projections.html for how to assign projections using geopandas. Note that the latest version (0.7) has a new syntax, so if you're using an older version, be wary.